# What HTTP response code will show up in a scenario where it can be 405 or 422?

Tags: php, backend, httpresponse

I am new to backend programming and I am messing around with HTTP responses and was wondering which HTTP response would show up if in my scenario I'm not sending complete data `422` and sending it with the wrong method `405` .

Comment: 405. I suggest to follow this (https://camo.githubusercontent.com/4e15cccf2a9277dcca2c8824092547dee7058744/68747470733a2f2f7261776769746875622e636f6d2f666f722d4745542f687474702d6465636973696f6e2d6469616772616d2f6d61737465722f6874747064642e706e67) schema to determine which status code you should use.

Comment: You can write your controllers as you want - you may return eg. 404 or 500 whenever you want even if this deosn't make sense however it's not a good idea because it confuses frontend devs and users. There is also other way of returning errors - endpoints always return 200 ok, but instead you return json like: `{"success": false, "error": "WTF stormtroopers are here"}`